# Port to use CentOS init.d functions

Tags: centos

What are good equivalent centos commands using functions in `/etc/init.d/functions` such as `daemon` to perform the following tasks?

```
STARTCMD='start-stop-daemon --start --exec /usr/sbin/swapspace --quiet --pidfile /var/run/swapspace.pid -- -d -p'
STOPCMD='start-stop-daemon --stop --oknodo --quiet --pidfile /var/run/swapspace.pid'
```

It looks like `daemon` will work for the start command and `killproc` is used for the stop command.

```
 . /etc/init.d/functions
 pushd /usr/sbin
 daemon --pidfile /var/run/swapspace.pid /usr/sbin/swapspace

 . /etc/init.d/functions
 killproc -p $(cat /var/run/swapspace.pid)
```

Would the --oknodo be needed in the CentOS env (the swap file is really only boot-time)? "oknodo - Return exit status 0 instead of 1 if no actions are (would be) taken."

I don't see quiet in `daemon` or `killproc`, I can't imagine that it would matter though.

The original start-stop-daemon for swapspace seems to have both -p and --pidfile (the same command).  That must be an error.

Did I miss anything?  Any idea why daemon not create the pid file?

Comment: [This `daemon` helper tool](http://libslack.org/daemon/) makes a good `start-stop-daemon` replacement.  It expects its argument program not to fork and takes care of restarting/stopping/checking if its running [with the appropriate arguments](http://libslack.org/daemon/manpages/daemon.1.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It looks like `daemon` will work for the start command and `killproc` is used for the stop command.

These are just shell functions defined in `/etc/rc.d/init.d/functions`. They're not as sophisticated as `start-stop-daemon`, but are pretty much what you have to work with on CentOS.

> Would the `--oknodo` be needed in the CentOS env (the swap file is really only boot-time)?

`daemon` and `killproc` don't have that option so you don't. `daemon` will exit successfully if the process is already running so that's fine. I'm not sure how `killproc` will behave -- you may need to explicitly check whether the process is running before calling it.

> The original start-stop-daemon for swapspace seems to have both `-p` and `--pidfile` (the same command). That must be an error.

It's not: `--pidfile` is a parameter to `start-stop-daemon`, while `-p` is a parameter to `swapspace`. The `--` separates parameters to `start-stop-daemon` from parameters to the process being started.

> Did I miss anything? Any idea why daemon not create the pid file?

You need to pass `-p` to `swapspace`, like this:

```
daemon --pidfile /var/run/swapspace.pid /usr/sbin/swapspace -p
```